# jstl bigdecimal addition inside c:foreach?

Tags: jsp, jstl, bigdecimal, addition

What is wrong with the below syntax?

```
 <c:set var="returnAmt" value="${0.00}"/> 
 <c:forEach items="${stPts.olList}" var="Item" varStatus="counterMap">
    <c:if test="${Item.originalDollarValue.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) ne 0}">
        <c:set var="returnAmtVal" value="${returnAmt + Item.originalDollarValue}" />
    </c:if>
 </c:foreach>
```

I am always getting 0.00 as returnAmtVal when I `c:out` it..

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal addition is supported using method [add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add%28java.math.BigDecimal%29)

Please note that result of operation must be assigned to variable:

```
BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.ZERO; //a=0
a = a.add(BigDecimal.TEN);      //a=10
```

Thus assuming that **Item.originalDollarValue** is **BigDecimal** your JSP must be something like:

```
<c:set var="returnAmtVal" value="${returnAmtVal.add(Item.originalDollarValue)}"/>
```